# Get product categories on single product page issue in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to get product's categories on `single-product.php`
 I am trying this code

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
```

but `$terms` returns a empty 
how can get products categories

Answer (score 1):

use [get_the_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/)

```
get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat');
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because sometimes you need first to declare:

```
global $post;
```

Then now this will not be empty:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

// Testing output
echo '<pre>'; print_r($terms); echo '</pre>';
```

You will get an array of product categories `WP_Term` objects for this product.

> **Or you can just use:**
>
> ```
> $terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_cat' );
> ```

Comment: @AlexVand No… What is loaded is `$product` depending how and where you put the code.

Comment: Mmh ... I have a custom post type `"recipe"` and I created a `single-recipe.php` . If I add `var_dump($post)` wherever in the file, I get the post. You edited your answer by adding an easier way that would be to use get_the_id(). This function use the `global $post` to get the title, and there is no need to do call `global $post` before it. This demonstrated that for your first answer you don't either need to call it.

Comment: @AlexVand it depend on which template or if it is a hooked function… If the product has product categories wp_get_post_terms() with the correct post ID works… So the problem is the post Id or product ID… That's all. I will not discuss that further.